# Woocommerce - : Sorry, this product cannot be purchased

Tags: woocommerce

my woocommerce was working but all of sudden i am getting this error when i try to add product to cart. “Sorry, this product cannot be purchased.”

I haven’t done any modification in the theme.

please help

Answer (score 1):

That error has only appeared to me when the product I want to add has not Price (Regular Price, Variable Price or any default price) set AND I try to add it directly through URL parameters (it also applies when adding an out of stock product).

Can you provide more info? You try to add it with the Ajax Button? or other method? The Product you have, has price/stock set?
I just made a quick test in my site and its the same error message
[image: A Quick Test on My Site]

Comment: Great! Great! Great! Woo Commerce People should tell this loudly.